# View gets disappeared and shakes up on onTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-layout, view, touch, ontouchlistener

I have a layout where I am putting a view over it and moving only in horizontal direction. I managed to do so, but the issue is the dragging is not very smooth, it shakes alot and sometimes ends up on wrong coordinates.

Apart from it when I play alot with that view, it disappears from the layout.

Here is mu xml file

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/drag_line"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@drawable/line"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:src="@drawable/line" />

</FrameLayout>
```

here is my onTouch event handler of view,

```
  line.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            final int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            final int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
            final int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();


            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
             `enter code here`   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    int currentX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                    params.rightMargin = (params.rightMargin - (currentX));
                    params.leftMargin = (params.leftMargin + (currentX));
                    line.setLayoutParams(params);
                    line.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                        dynamicUpdate(line.getX());
                        touchFlag = true;

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I want to handle a condition on ACTION_Up.

I could not understand why the view is shaking over layout on touch move and sometimes getting disappear.

Comment: Don't know if it will be helpful now, but dropping it anyways. You might want to see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273249/android-ontouchevent-coordinates-skip-around

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem，`event.getX()` is the coordinate of the view.
If your view moves, then the coordinate of same point in screen will change, so it shakes. You should use `event.getRawX()` and `event.getRawY()`